# Import modules outside django root

Tags: python, django, python-import, python-module

I have a folder structure like this

```
Project/


        Common-resuable-code-i-wrote/
                                     folder1
                                     folder2
        WebApp/
               templates/
               views
               urls
               etc
```

I am trying to import folder1 from a module  within the webapp folder. The webserver starts but when i request a page which uses this code it throws an exception about not being able to find the module. Is there a way to get this to work without refactoring everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your PYTHONPATH to be Project or a parent folder of Project

http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

After doing this, or if you already have done this, insert a file called __init__.py in your Common-reusable-code-i-wrote folder, and all subfolders inside there that you want to import code from.